# How to modify ASP.NET Core routes mapping after WebHost is started

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, kestrel-http-server

I run WebHost with Kestrel in my ASP.NET Core application. I use simple routing model without MVC. The relevant configuration code:

```
_host = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseConfiguration(_config)
.UseKestrel()
.ConfigureServices(services => services.AddRouting())
.Configure(app =>
        {
            app.UseRouter(r =>
            {
                r.MapGet("some_uri_template", request_handler);

                r.MapPost("some_other_uri", other_handler);
            });
        })
        .Build();
_host.Run(_token.Token);
```

This simple service works as expected. But sometimes I need to modify mapped routes dynamically: remove some routes, add other routes, or change handler method for a particular route after WebHost has already been started.
How can I do that?